# CRC32 Calculation With Pycrc and PHP code Doesn't Match Expected Result

Tags: php, c++, python, c, crc32

I was trying to convert a CRC32 algorithm defined as a C/C++ macro

```
unsigned long sctp_crc_c[256] = {
0x00000000L, 0xF26B8303L, 0xE13B70F7L, 0x1350F3F4L,
0xC79A971FL, 0x35F1141CL, 0x26A1E7E8L, 0xD4CA64EBL,
0x8AD958CFL, 0x78B2DBCCL, 0x6BE22838L, 0x9989AB3BL,
0x4D43CFD0L, 0xBF284CD3L, 0xAC78BF27L, 0x5E133C24L,
0x105EC76FL, 0xE235446CL, 0xF165B798L, 0x030E349BL,
0xD7C45070L, 0x25AFD373L, 0x36FF2087L, 0xC494A384L,
0x9A879FA0L, 0x68EC1CA3L, 0x7BBCEF57L, 0x89D76C54L,
0x5D1D08BFL, 0xAF768BBCL, 0xBC267848L, 0x4E4DFB4BL,
0x20BD8EDEL, 0xD2D60DDDL, 0xC186FE29L, 0x33ED7D2AL,
0xE72719C1L, 0x154C9AC2L, 0x061C6936L, 0xF477EA35L,
0xAA64D611L, 0x580F5512L, 0x4B5FA6E6L, 0xB93425E5L,
0x6DFE410EL, 0x9F95C20DL, 0x8CC531F9L, 0x7EAEB2FAL,
0x30E349B1L, 0xC288CAB2L, 0xD1D83946L, 0x23B3BA45L,
0xF779DEAEL, 0x05125DADL, 0x1642AE59L, 0xE4292D5AL,
0xBA3A117EL, 0x4851927DL, 0x5B016189L, 0xA96AE28AL,
0x7DA08661L, 0x8FCB0562L, 0x9C9BF696L, 0x6EF07595L,
0x417B1DBCL, 0xB3109EBFL, 0xA0406D4BL, 0x522BEE48L,
0x86E18AA3L, 0x748A09A0L, 0x67DAFA54L, 0x95B17957L,
0xCBA24573L, 0x39C9C670L, 0x2A993584L, 0xD8F2B687L,
0x0C38D26CL, 0xFE53516FL, 0xED03A29BL, 0x1F682198L,
0x5125DAD3L, 0xA34E59D0L, 0xB01EAA24L, 0x42752927L,
0x96BF4DCCL, 0x64D4CECFL, 0x77843D3BL, 0x85EFBE38L,
0xDBFC821CL, 0x2997011FL, 0x3AC7F2EBL, 0xC8AC71E8L,
0x1C661503L, 0xEE0D9600L, 0xFD5D65F4L, 0x0F36E6F7L,
0x61C69362L, 0x93AD1061L, 0x80FDE395L, 0x72966096L,
0xA65C047DL, 0x5437877EL, 0x4767748AL, 0xB50CF789L,
0xEB1FCBADL, 0x197448AEL, 0x0A24BB5AL, 0xF84F3859L,
0x2C855CB2L, 0xDEEEDFB1L, 0xCDBE2C45L, 0x3FD5AF46L,
0x7198540DL, 0x83F3D70EL, 0x90A324FAL, 0x62C8A7F9L,
0xB602C312L, 0x44694011L, 0x5739B3E5L, 0xA55230E6L,
0xFB410CC2L, 0x092A8FC1L, 0x1A7A7C35L, 0xE811FF36L,
0x3CDB9BDDL, 0xCEB018DEL, 0xDDE0EB2AL, 0x2F8B6829L,
0x82F63B78L, 0x709DB87BL, 0x63CD4B8FL, 0x91A6C88CL,
0x456CAC67L, 0xB7072F64L, 0xA457DC90L, 0x563C5F93L,
0x082F63B7L, 0xFA44E0B4L, 0xE9141340L, 0x1B7F9043L,
0xCFB5F4A8L, 0x3DDE77ABL, 0x2E8E845FL, 0xDCE5075CL,
0x92A8FC17L, 0x60C37F14L, 0x73938CE0L, 0x81F80FE3L,
0x55326B08L, 0xA759E80BL, 0xB4091BFFL, 0x466298FCL,
0x1871A4D8L, 0xEA1A27DBL, 0xF94AD42FL, 0x0B21572CL,
0xDFEB33C7L, 0x2D80B0C4L, 0x3ED04330L, 0xCCBBC033L,
0xA24BB5A6L, 0x502036A5L, 0x4370C551L, 0xB11B4652L,
0x65D122B9L, 0x97BAA1BAL, 0x84EA524EL, 0x7681D14DL,
0x2892ED69L, 0xDAF96E6AL, 0xC9A99D9EL, 0x3BC21E9DL,
0xEF087A76L, 0x1D63F975L, 0x0E330A81L, 0xFC588982L,
0xB21572C9L, 0x407EF1CAL, 0x532E023EL, 0xA145813DL,
0x758FE5D6L, 0x87E466D5L, 0x94B49521L, 0x66DF1622L,
0x38CC2A06L, 0xCAA7A905L, 0xD9F75AF1L, 0x2B9CD9F2L,
0xFF56BD19L, 0x0D3D3E1AL, 0x1E6DCDEEL, 0xEC064EEDL,
0xC38D26C4L, 0x31E6A5C7L, 0x22B65633L, 0xD0DDD530L,
0x0417B1DBL, 0xF67C32D8L, 0xE52CC12CL, 0x1747422FL,
0x49547E0BL, 0xBB3FFD08L, 0xA86F0EFCL, 0x5A048DFFL,
0x8ECEE914L, 0x7CA56A17L, 0x6FF599E3L, 0x9D9E1AE0L,
0xD3D3E1ABL, 0x21B862A8L, 0x32E8915CL, 0xC083125FL,
0x144976B4L, 0xE622F5B7L, 0xF5720643L, 0x07198540L,
0x590AB964L, 0xAB613A67L, 0xB831C993L, 0x4A5A4A90L,
0x9E902E7BL, 0x6CFBAD78L, 0x7FAB5E8CL, 0x8DC0DD8FL,
0xE330A81AL, 0x115B2B19L, 0x020BD8EDL, 0xF0605BEEL,
0x24AA3F05L, 0xD6C1BC06L, 0xC5914FF2L, 0x37FACCF1L,
0x69E9F0D5L, 0x9B8273D6L, 0x88D28022L, 0x7AB90321L,
0xAE7367CAL, 0x5C18E4C9L, 0x4F48173DL, 0xBD23943EL,
0xF36E6F75L, 0x0105EC76L, 0x12551F82L, 0xE03E9C81L,
0x34F4F86AL, 0xC69F7B69L, 0xD5CF889DL, 0x27A40B9EL,
0x79B737BAL, 0x8BDCB4B9L, 0x988C474DL, 0x6AE7C44EL,
0xBE2DA0A5L, 0x4C4623A6L, 0x5F16D052L, 0xAD7D5351L,
};

#define SCTP_CRC32C(c, d) (c = ((c) >> 8) ^ sctp_crc_c[((c) ^ (d)) & 0xFF])

UINT32 CRC32_F_calc(UINT32 crc32, unsigned char *buffer, unsigned int length)
{
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
       SCTP_CRC32C(crc32, buffer[i]);
    }

    return (crc32);
}
```

into a PHP code ([already asked once for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413594/crc32-from-c-c-to-php)) and I couldn't get the result output the same as the C++ one. The input is (128 bytes binary) displayed as hex string:

> CC9F786E57B408F83EE907D32D1D7FA6F180632E1CBE97AE717B2CD964EBB5E71E97B49619E8CD7A94DA0CDD06083D169618017FB8A1722F21FFD609EA655665F8881B05AFE0B282B186E0B8A4A5C26727778EC6639592776E392996430D47143F740E541E3755B1627ECD31C1B98A7C3D010AE273D6900263F6A49600000000

and the expected CRC32 in hex is **956E04C6** . It's OK even if it's in reverse order, but I MUST produce that exact value.

The algorithm calculates the code in chunks and the only other MUST is a starting **crc32 = 7** i.e. the initial CRC value for the function **CRC32_F_calc**, and the bytes (displayed as hex string) for the buffer are actually 128 in length.

What I could get wasn't even close, so I checked the [pycrc](http://www.tty1.net/pycrc/pycrc.html) program, but also couldn't get it to work. Here is what happened:

the command (with [parameters for crc-32c](http://www.tty1.net/pycrc/crc-models_en.html#crc-32c) and xor-in changed to  0x7)

```
 ./pycrc.py --check-hexstring CC...<same string as above>...9600000000 --verbose --width 32 --poly 0x1edc6f41 --reflect-in True --xor-in 0x7 --reflect-out True --xor-out 0xffffffff --algorithm table-driven
```

the output

```
Width        = 32
Poly         = 0x1edc6f41
ReflectIn    = True
XorIn        = 0x00000007
ReflectOut   = True
XorOut       = 0xffffffff
Algorithm    = table-driven

0xab2c9624
```

I don't know what I'm missing. I have very little time to make it happen (few hours), so even the python program (with correct parameters) is good if I can call it from the PHP application.

The PHP code I got so far is:

```
function hex2str($hex)
{
    $string = '';
    $length = strlen($hex);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length - 1; $i += 2)
    {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i] . $hex[$i + 1]));
    }
    return $string;
}

function str2hex($string)
{
    $hex = '';
    $length = strlen($string);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return strtoupper($hex);
}

function crc32c($string = '', $hex = false)
{

    $crc_array = array(0x00000000, 0xF26B8303, 0xE13B70F7, 0x1350F3F4, 0xC79A971F, 0x35F1141C, 0x26A1E7E8, 0xD4CA64EB, 0x8AD958CF, 0x78B2DBCC, 0x6BE22838, 0x9989AB3B, 0x4D43CFD0, 0xBF284CD3, 0xAC78BF27, 0x5E133C24, 0x105EC76F, 0xE235446C, 0xF165B798, 0x030E349B, 0xD7C45070, 0x25AFD373, 0x36FF2087, 0xC494A384, 0x9A879FA0, 0x68EC1CA3, 0x7BBCEF57, 0x89D76C54, 0x5D1D08BF, 0xAF768BBC, 0xBC267848, 0x4E4DFB4B, 0x20BD8EDE, 0xD2D60DDD, 0xC186FE29, 0x33ED7D2A, 0xE72719C1, 0x154C9AC2, 0x061C6936, 0xF477EA35, 0xAA64D611, 0x580F5512, 0x4B5FA6E6, 0xB93425E5, 0x6DFE410E, 0x9F95C20D, 0x8CC531F9, 0x7EAEB2FA, 0x30E349B1, 0xC288CAB2, 0xD1D83946, 0x23B3BA45, 0xF779DEAE, 0x05125DAD, 0x1642AE59, 0xE4292D5A, 0xBA3A117E, 0x4851927D, 0x5B016189, 0xA96AE28A, 0x7DA08661, 0x8FCB0562, 0x9C9BF696, 0x6EF07595, 0x417B1DBC, 0xB3109EBF, 0xA0406D4B, 0x522BEE48, 0x86E18AA3, 0x748A09A0, 0x67DAFA54, 0x95B17957, 0xCBA24573, 0x39C9C670, 0x2A993584, 0xD8F2B687, 0x0C38D26C, 0xFE53516F, 0xED03A29B, 0x1F682198, 0x5125DAD3, 0xA34E59D0, 0xB01EAA24, 0x42752927, 0x96BF4DCC, 0x64D4CECF, 0x77843D3B, 0x85EFBE38, 0xDBFC821C, 0x2997011F, 0x3AC7F2EB, 0xC8AC71E8, 0x1C661503, 0xEE0D9600, 0xFD5D65F4, 0x0F36E6F7, 0x61C69362, 0x93AD1061, 0x80FDE395, 0x72966096, 0xA65C047D, 0x5437877E, 0x4767748A, 0xB50CF789, 0xEB1FCBAD, 0x197448AE, 0x0A24BB5A, 0xF84F3859, 0x2C855CB2, 0xDEEEDFB1, 0xCDBE2C45, 0x3FD5AF46, 0x7198540D, 0x83F3D70E, 0x90A324FA, 0x62C8A7F9, 0xB602C312, 0x44694011, 0x5739B3E5, 0xA55230E6, 0xFB410CC2, 0x092A8FC1, 0x1A7A7C35, 0xE811FF36, 0x3CDB9BDD, 0xCEB018DE, 0xDDE0EB2A, 0x2F8B6829, 0x82F63B78, 0x709DB87B, 0x63CD4B8F, 0x91A6C88C, 0x456CAC67, 0xB7072F64, 0xA457DC90, 0x563C5F93, 0x082F63B7, 0xFA44E0B4, 0xE9141340, 0x1B7F9043, 0xCFB5F4A8, 0x3DDE77AB, 0x2E8E845F, 0xDCE5075C, 0x92A8FC17, 0x60C37F14, 0x73938CE0, 0x81F80FE3, 0x55326B08, 0xA759E80B, 0xB4091BFF, 0x466298FC, 0x1871A4D8, 0xEA1A27DB, 0xF94AD42F, 0x0B21572C, 0xDFEB33C7, 0x2D80B0C4, 0x3ED04330, 0xCCBBC033, 0xA24BB5A6, 0x502036A5, 0x4370C551, 0xB11B4652, 0x65D122B9, 0x97BAA1BA, 0x84EA524E, 0x7681D14D, 0x2892ED69, 0xDAF96E6A, 0xC9A99D9E, 0x3BC21E9D, 0xEF087A76, 0x1D63F975, 0x0E330A81, 0xFC588982, 0xB21572C9, 0x407EF1CA, 0x532E023E, 0xA145813D, 0x758FE5D6, 0x87E466D5, 0x94B49521, 0x66DF1622, 0x38CC2A06, 0xCAA7A905, 0xD9F75AF1, 0x2B9CD9F2, 0xFF56BD19, 0x0D3D3E1A, 0x1E6DCDEE, 0xEC064EED, 0xC38D26C4, 0x31E6A5C7, 0x22B65633, 0xD0DDD530, 0x0417B1DB, 0xF67C32D8, 0xE52CC12C, 0x1747422F, 0x49547E0B, 0xBB3FFD08, 0xA86F0EFC, 0x5A048DFF, 0x8ECEE914, 0x7CA56A17, 0x6FF599E3, 0x9D9E1AE0, 0xD3D3E1AB, 0x21B862A8, 0x32E8915C, 0xC083125F, 0x144976B4, 0xE622F5B7, 0xF5720643, 0x07198540, 0x590AB964, 0xAB613A67, 0xB831C993, 0x4A5A4A90, 0x9E902E7B, 0x6CFBAD78, 0x7FAB5E8C, 0x8DC0DD8F, 0xE330A81A, 0x115B2B19, 0x020BD8ED, 0xF0605BEE, 0x24AA3F05, 0xD6C1BC06, 0xC5914FF2, 0x37FACCF1, 0x69E9F0D5, 0x9B8273D6, 0x88D28022, 0x7AB90321, 0xAE7367CA, 0x5C18E4C9, 0x4F48173D, 0xBD23943E, 0xF36E6F75, 0x0105EC76, 0x12551F82, 0xE03E9C81, 0x34F4F86A, 0xC69F7B69, 0xD5CF889D, 0x27A40B9E, 0x79B737BA, 0x8BDCB4B9, 0x988C474D, 0x6AE7C44E, 0xBE2DA0A5, 0x4C4623A6, 0x5F16D052, 0xAD7D5351, );
    $crc_array_hex = array_map('dechex', $crc_array);
    echo "\ncrc_array: " . implode(', ', $crc_array_hex) . "\n";

    if ($hex)
    {
        $string = hex2str($string);
    }

    $length = strlen($string);
    $crc32 = 7;
    echo "\nlength of string: $length, starting crc32: $crc32\n\n";
    echo "step\tdata\tindex\tcrc32\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $data = (int)ord($string[$i]);
        $index = 0xFF & (int)($crc32 ^ $data);
        $crc32 = (int)($crc32>>8) ^ $crc_array[$index];
        echo "$i\t$data\t$index\t" . dechex($crc32) . "\n";
    }

    return $crc32;

}

echo "<pre>\n";
$hex_string = 'CC9F786E57B408F83EE907D32D1D7FA6F180632E1CBE97AE717B2CD964EBB5E71E97B49619E8CD7A94DA0CDD06083D169618017FB8A1722F21FFD609EA655665F8881B05AFE0B282B186E0B8A4A5C26727778EC6639592776E392996430D47143F740E541E3755B1627ECD31C1B98A7C3D010AE273D6900263F6A49600000000';
echo "\nresult: " . dechex(crc32c($hex_string, true));
echo "\nexpected: 956E04C6 or C6046E95\n\n";
```

Comment: By the way, if you need php code, why isn't one of your tags php?

Comment: The tag PHP was on the other question, this is a question of making the pycrc work "correctly".

Comment: Now I'm confused.  At the end of your question you say you're looking for something you can call from your PHP application.  You can write that code in PHP, and call it from your PHP application.  If your PHP code is not generating the correct result, then post that code in your question.

Comment: I must be suffering with the worst case of tunnel vision I guess :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provided C code produces the answer you expect, which is 0xc6046e95.  When written out in little-endian order, which is probably what you were seeing, the result is 95 6e 04 c6.

Simply translate that code from C to php, and it will produce the same answer.  php has 32-bit integers and bitwise operators that do the same thing.

You need to be careful with the difference between signed and unsigned integers.  When shifting down an unsigned integer, as in the C code, it will be filled in at the top with zeros.  When shifting down a signed integer, which is all that php has, the top will be filled in with the sign bit, i.e. the very top bit of what was there at the start.  So to emulate the unsigned behavior, you need to "and"-out those bits:

```
unsigned int c;
(c) >> 8
```

becomes:

```
int c;
((c) >> 8) & 0xffffff
```

to do the same thing.  So your php code needs to read:

```
$crc32 = ((int)($crc32>>8) & 0xffffff) ^ $crc_array[$index];
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I know what the number should be because there actually is an application that generates that awkward code. I have updated the quiestion a bit to explain the 7. What remains is the actual table, which the first time I replicated in the PHP code, with no luck.

Comment: The provided code DOES produce it, I need to produce it also with php or pycrc. For example doing
./pycrc.py --verbose --width=32 --poly=0x1EDC6F41  --reflect-in=True --xor-in=0x7 --reflect-out=True --xor-out=0x0 --algorithm=table-driven --check-hexstring=CC9F786E57B408F83EE907D32D1D7FA6F180632E1CBE97AE717B2CD964EBB5E71E97B49619E8CD7A94DA0CDD06083D169618017FB8A1722F21FFD609EA655665F8881B05AFE0B282B186E0B8A4A5C26727778EC6639592776E392996430D47143F740E541E3755B1627ECD31C1B98A7C3D010AE273D6900263F6A49600000000
i got 0x54d369db
and the PHP code above produces 0x815db0b1

Comment: Then simply translate the provided code into php.  You don't need pycrc.

Comment: The PHP code above is the "simply translate" I did even before posting this question :( Even before actually trying out pycrc

Comment: Here is the actual code I'm trying out http://at.azder.mk/NJMGKY with the output.

Comment: Unless I have eye troubles, that code works. I am getting: 
result: c6046e95
expected: 956E04C6 or C6046E95

Comment: See my answer above.  You need to fix the shift down operation due to php's signed integers.  (And yes @lserni, you need to check your eyes.  The previous code was giving the wrong answer, 815db0b1.  With the fix it correctly gives c6046e95.)

Comment: @Azder: if you had written the php code you posted here before you put in your first question ("CRC32 From C++/C# to PHP"), then you could have had this answer over a week ago.  Next time, simply post the code that's not working.

Comment: @MarkAdler: my eyes are okay, possibly my comments might benefit from being more specific. I was referring to Azder's code posted at at.azder.mk. When I downloaded and ran it, it gave the results I quoted, honest. :-D

Comment: @lserni: ok, I believe you.  When I ran that same code, it gave the wrong answer that I quoted.  It is possible that the difference is that your php is using 64-bit signed integers, whereas my php and Azder's php is using 32-bit signed integers.  The problem should not occur with 64-bit integers, since the sign bit in that case never gets set by the 32-bit values in the table.

Comment: ...as you surmised, the machine I ran the tests on was indeed 64bit. I could EVEN NOW swear to the contrary, but uname leaves me no opening. My eyes are all right; they're just plugged into an idiot, is all :-(

Comment: @ Mark Adler if I had the code a week ago I would've posted it a week ago :) Thanks for the help. Although just before reading your "shift is not working" answer I had a friend make a python version and we went step by step with it. Basically what I needed was another set of eyes (pun intended) :)

Comment: just a note: I ran the PHP code on 64 bit LAMPs and WAMPs, it was always shifting "wrong".

Comment: Just because the Linux is 64 bits doesn't mean that php is necessarily using 64-bit integers.